# Running Both Virtualbox and Android Virtual Device Manager on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine, android, android-studio

Both Virtualbox and Android Studio's Android Virtual Device Manager (AVD) needs to be able to run on my Ubuntu 20.04 machine containing AMD Ryzen 3950X.

If KVM is disabled (such as by adding `kvm_amd` to `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`, Virtualbox is able to run but not Android Studio AVD. Starting an AVD Virtual Device will give the error

> Could not start AVD

[image]

However, if KVM is enabled, then Virtualbox is not able to run, but Android Studio AVD runs now.

> VirtualBox can't enable the AMD-V extension. Please disable the KVM kernel extension, recompile your kernel and reboot (VERR_SVM_IN_USE).

Is there a way to allow both AVD virtual devices and Virtualbox VM to run at the same time? Or at least run one at a time, but able to stop the first and run the second one without restarting the machine?

Thanks!

Comment: Will the kernel have to be recompiled for each kernel update in Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: I have similar problem in that I'm running a RAD tool (named B4a which is a Windows program) for developing Android apps under Windows 10 VM in VirtualBox running in Ubuntu 20.04. I think I may have found the solution: a web page for " Android Emulator Hypervisor Driver for AMD Processors is now available for download via SDK Manager in the Canary channel" at androidstudio.googleblog.com/2019/10/… Just one problem to solve in order to try it: what is the Canary channel for SDK Manager e.g. does it refer to a particular version of platform-tools/build-tools?